# Extract text from a string

Tags: regex, string, text, powershell

How do I extract the "program name" from a string. The string will look like this :

> %  O0033(SUB RAD MSD 50R III)  G91G1X-6.4Z-2.F500  G3I6.4Z-8.  G3I6.4 
>   G3R3.2X6.4F500  G91G0Z5.  G91G1X-10.4 G3I10.4 G3R5.2X10.4 G90G0Z2. 
>   M99 %

The program name is (SUB RAD MSD 50R III).  Storing the result in another string is fine.  I'm learning powershell so any explaination of your answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Will program name always be in the (), or will it always start at 7th character?

Comment: There are multiple lines with "()" in the other files im working with. The program i need is in the first brackets. The pattern is "%" on the first line, second line starts with "O" and then a 4 digit number "????" and then the program is in the brackets strait after.  Hope this helps guys

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The following regex extract anything between the parenthesis:

```
PS> $prog = [regex]::match($s,'\(([^\)]+)\)').Groups[1].Value
PS> $prog
SUB RAD MSD 50R III
```

Explanation (created with RegexBuddy)

```
Match the character '(' literally «\(»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\)]+)»
   Match any character that is NOT a ) character «[^\)]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character ')' literally «\)»
```

**Further Reading**:

- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)
- [Regular Expressions Are Your Friend (Part 1)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220043057/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/10/27/regular-expressions-are-your-friend-part-1.aspx)
- [Regular Expressions Are Your Friend (Part 2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407003521/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/12/02/regular-expressions-are-your-friend-part-2.aspx)
- [Regular Expressions Are Your Friend (Part 3)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818092304/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/12/02/regular-expressions-are-your-friend-part-3.aspx)

Answer (score 20):

If program name is always the first thing in (), and doesn't contain other )s than the one at end, then `$yourstring -match "[(][^)]+[)]"` does the matching, result will be in `$Matches[0]`

Comment: ...and since `-match` returns a boolean, you probably want something like `if($something -match "regexp") { $Matches[0] } else { '' }` in an expression context.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a non-regex solution:

```
'(' + $myString.Split('()')[1] + ')'
```

This splits the string at the parentheses and takes the string from the array with the program name in it.

If you don't need the parentheses, just use:

```
$myString.Split('()')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using -replace

```
 $string = '% O0033(SUB RAD MSD 50R III) G91G1X-6.4Z-2.F500 G3I6.4Z-8.G3I6.4 G3R3.2X6.4F500 G91G0Z5. G91G1X-10.4 G3I10.4 G3R5.2X10.4 G90G0Z2. M99 %'
 $program = $string -replace '^%\sO\d{4}\((.+?)\).+$','$1'
 $program

SUB RAD MSD 50R III
```

Comment: There are multiple lines with "()".  The pattern is

Comment: regex adjusted for new requirements