# Need to Filter only the KBxxxx article and remaining text separtely on below code result

Tags: powershell

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()

$a=$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Title 

$a
```

Request you to kindly help me to filter only `KBxxxx,softwarenamelist` for the above command output.

Comment: What is `softwarenamelist`?

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. James C
"Update for Microsoft Word 2013 (KB4011045) 64-Bit Edition"  result of the above command i need to get format as "KB4011045","Update for Microsoft Word 2013 (KB4011045) 64-Bit Edition"

Request you to kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113231/powershell-extract-text-from-a-string) to capture the KB Number from between the parentheses, and then [Calculated Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to make it neat:

```
$a = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object @{Name="KB";Expression={[regex]::match($_.Title,'\(([^\)]+)\)').Groups[1].Value}},@{Name="Title";Expression={$_.Title}}
```

Comment: Its working fine Thank you very much. how can we format this expression including double quotes ""KB4011045","Update for Microsoft Word 2013 64-Bit Edition"  and remove unwanted space between 2 columns and KBxxxxx details need to be hided in title list.

Comment: $a = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object @{Name="KB";Expression={'"'+[regex]::match($_.Title,'\(([^\)]+)\)').Groups[1].Value+'"'}}, @{Name="Title";Expression={','+'"'+$_.Title +'"'}} 

i have added quotes and command as per the above code but how to remove the unwanted space between KB&title i would like to get the output format as "KB4011045","Update for Microsoft Word 2013 64-Bit Edition" but i am managed to get "KB4011045"                    ,"Update for Microsoft Word 2013 (KB4011045) 64-Bit Edition" i want to remove the unwanted space between kb and namelist.please.

Comment: i have rectified the space issue, request you to kindly guide me to hide Update for Microsoft Word 2013 (KB4011045) 64-Bit Edition  in this i would to see only Update for Microsoft Word 2013 64-Bit Edition how to hide the KBXXXX using regex

Answer (score 0):

You could try this at the end of your own code :

```
$arrayKb = @()

foreach($strKb in $a){
    $strKb -match "KB\d{7}"
    $kb = $Matches[0]

    $itemObject = New-Object System.Object
    $itemObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Kb" -Value $kb
    $itemObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Software" -Value $strKb
    $arrayKb += $itemObject
}

$arrayKb
```