# Not able to extract value from System.Array in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I am trying to write a script. In that, I have an array $spCreated.

Its variable type is:

- Name: Object[]
- BaseType: System.Array

The $spCreated contains the value below:

```
[
  {
    "accountEnabled": "True",
    "addIns": [],
    "alternativeNames": [],
    "appDisplayName": "testSP4",
    "appId": "abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234",
    "appOwnerTenantId": "",
    "appRoleAssignmentRequired": false,
    "appRoles": [],
    "applicationTemplateId": null,
    "deletionTimestamp": null,
    "displayName": "testSP4",
    "errorUrl": null,
    "homepage": null,
    "informationalUrls": {
      "marketing": null,
      "privacy": null,
      "support": null,
      "termsOfService": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "notificationEmailAddresses": [],
    "oauth2Permissions": [
      {
        "adminConsentDescription": "text",
        "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access testSP4",
        "id": "ab123-ab123-ab123-ab123-ab123",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "type": "User",
        "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access testSP4 on your behalf.",
        "userConsentDisplayName": "Access testSP4",
        "value": "user_impersonation"
      }
    ],
    "objectId": "abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234",
    "servicePrincipalType": "Application",
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
  }
]
```

How can I get the value of objectId in a string variable?

I have tried the commands:

```
$z = $spCreated-match 'objectId'
$b = $z.Substring(15, $z.Length-1)
```

But it returns (with the quotes and comma)

```
"abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234",
```

I just want `abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234` as a string.
Can I please get help on this? Thanks

Comment: wouldnt it be easier to `(ConvertFrom-Json $spCreated).objectId` ?

Comment: Definitely what @SantiagoSquarzon said. But even if you *didn't* do that, you just need to slightly adjust your `Substring` parameters. You could figure it out with a few seconds of trial and error.

Comment: Its not working for me. 'It says: annot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'InputObject'. Specified method is not supported.'

Comment: Try this instead `($spCreated | ConvertFrom-Json).objectId`

Comment: My bad, should've given the pipeline example. Martin's example should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the elements of your input string constitute a JSON document, the simplest and *robust* approach is to parse that document with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Json) and the access the property of interest, as [Martin Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20553/martin-brown) showed in a comment:

```bash
$value = 
  ($spCreated | ConvertFrom-Json).objectId # -> abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234
```

---

If you do want to - suboptimally - solve this problem with *string parsing* and [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement :

```bash
$value = 
  switch -Regex ($spCreated) {
    '"objectId":\s*"(.+?)"' { $Matches.1 }
  } # -> abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234
```

Note the use of the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) to reference what the first (`.1`) (and only) capture group in the regex (`(.+?)`) captured.

---

An alternative solution with a simpler regex, which uses the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator to extract the part of the line of interest:

```bash
$value = 
  switch -Regex ($spCreated) {
    '"objectId":' { ($_ -split '"')[-2] }
  } # -> abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with the help  of regex:

```
$c = [regex]::match($b,'\"([^\)]+)\"').Groups[1].Value
```

The command above returned just the objectId in the string format.
Eg: `abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234-abc1234`

Reference: [Extract text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113231/extract-text-from-a-string)

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: It's commendable that you want to share a solution for the benefit of future readers, but it's unclear how your solution relates to the question you asked. Given that your string is clearly JSON, a solution using a parser such as [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Json), as suggested in the comments, is definitely preferable.

Comment: @mklement0: Yes true. I changed it to ConvertFrom-Json. I was able to extract the text from the above regex too. So I posted it here.

Comment: I see. If all you need to do is trim the enclosing `"` from a string, `$b.Trim('"')` will do. I've posted an answer that shows both the `ConvertFrom-Json` solution as well as a regex solution that requires just a single regex overall.